# Error “Cannot perform '=' operation on System.DateTime and System.String.” after changing locale

Tags: localization, datatable

We have a windows base application and my client needs to work in Italian language too.When I change my regional settings to Italy and run the program I get the below error message. 
“Cannot perform '=' operation on System.DateTime and System.String.”
Can anyone help me on this?
The code is given below.

```
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      dt.Columns.Add("Date",Type.GetType("System.DateTime"));

      TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);

        DateTime d = System.DateTime.Now;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Date"] = d.ToShortDateString();
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            d = d.AddDays(1.0);
        }

        DataRow[] dataRowArray = dt.Select("Date ="'8/31/2012'");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, shouldn't it be `dt.Select("Date ='8/31/2012'");`? (Note that I removed a `"`)

Second, where is `"8/31/2012"` coming from? It's not a valid date in Italy, so you need to get that right `("31/8/2012")`, and then it should work.

In other words, if it's coming from a database, then you have to do a locale conversion before doing the comparison.

Comment: The solution to your problem depends on where that date is coming from. User input? A database? The system date?